# Is it possible to augment macos finder's menus font size?

Tags: macos, finder, font

as per the object: is it possible to augment macos finder's menus font size? I don't mean files names, folder names... I mean menus font size:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no command or setting to adjust the size of the menubar. The only solution is to globally adjust the scaling of the display, so that all elements are larger.